# Como copiar otro directorio <origen> con COPY de Docker

Tags: docker

Este es mi proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver tenemos un carpeta docker, donde dentro tenemos los Dockerfile de Node y MongoDB.

Mi docker/node/Dockerfile

```
# Image on Docker Hub
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

# Create a new app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy project into container
COPY ../../ ./

RUN ls /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose server listen port
EXPOSE 3900

# Start node app
RUN npm start
```

El problema esta en la linea `COPY ../../ ./`, la cual queria que me copiara la raiz del proyecto, y en verdad si hacemos un `docker exec -it <ContainerID> ls /usr/src/app` podemos ver que solo ha copiado el Dockerfile de node, es decir el comando COPY no sale de la carpeta donde esta el Dockerfile.

Mi intención seria dejar el proyecto copiado en `/usr/src/app`.

Podemos comprobar que efectivamente solo copia el `/docker/node/Dockerfile`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación del comando [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy), y teniendo en cuenta que la sintáxis es `COPY <fuente>... <destino>`, la carpeta indicada en `<fuente>` debe:

> Estar dentro del contexto del `build`, no se puede hacer `COPY`
> `../directorio/directorio` porque el primer paso del `docker build` es
> enviar el directorio contexto (y subdirectorios) desde donde se
> ejecuta el `build` al demonio del docker.

En otras palabras, no se puede ir hacia atras en los directorios con `COPY`, siembre hacia adentro, a partir desde donde se hace el build.

Comment: No estoy seguro que sucede, habría que probar, si hacemos el build desde una carpeta mas arriba en la jerarquía pero apuntando a un Dockerfile que esta en un subdirectorio.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente tienes razón, cuando haces el build el Dockerfile solo puede trabajar con el directorio donde esta el mismo. Por lo segundo que comentas no lo he probado aún.